# Проблема с переопределением виртуальных функций.

Tags: qt

Пишу на Qt и возникла необходимость переопределить функцию keyPressEvent. Делаю я это так:

```
void glass::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *)
{
    // тело функции
}
```

где glass - имя класса. Однако, приложение никак не реагирует на нажатие клавиш, но стоит сменить имя класса на QWidget, как всё начинает работать. В чем может быть дело?

Объявление класса:

```
class glass : public QWidget
{

public:
    // Остальные функции

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*);

private:
};
```

Comment: покажите объявление класса glass

Comment: Доброго времени суток! В документации сказано, что для правильной обработки события нажатия на клавишу в Вашем виджете, очень важно внутри вашей реализации вызывать метод базового класса.

Comment: неплохо бы virtual добавить в объявлении keyPressEvent

Answer (score 1):

```
void glass::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    //
    // ...
    // 
    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```